# Find $\max\{t_k: t_k \leq t\}$, where $t_{k+1}-t_{k}=g(t_k)$, with $g(t_k)\to\infty$, and $t\in\mathbb{N}_{+}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Suppose we define a sequence $t_k$ generated by the difference relation $t_{k+1}-t_{k}=g(t_k)$, where $t_1$ is a positive integer, and $g(\cdot):\mathbb{N}_{+}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}_{+}$ is a monotonically increasing function of its argument. Given any $t\in\mathbb{N}_{+}$, I want an analytical expression for $f(t)=max\{t_k: t_k \leq t\}$. Is there a general technique that one can employ to solve this? For specific functional forms of $g(\cdot)$, (such as $g(t_k)=k$, or $g(t_k)=a^k$), this is fairly easy. But is there a unified way to find an analytical expression for the largest term in a sequence to the left of a given number, for a general growing function $g(\cdot)$?